# Calculate expected value in a gambling game

Tags: probability, expected-value

In a game the players can earn or lose $1$ dollar every round, the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{4}$. All the games are independent from each other. A player enter the game and play until he win for the first time (after that he leave the game). Let $X$ be the profit of the player. calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$

My attempt:

I understand that $X \leq 1$ so I assume that $\mathbb{E}[X]<0$
however I dont understand if $X$ is discrete or continuity.
The way that the player is playing is seems like $Geo(\frac{1}{4})$. I dont understand what I should do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W$ denote the event on winning at first game and let $L$ denote the event on losing at first game.

Then:$$\mathbb EX=P(W)\mathbb E(X\mid W)+P(L)\mathbb E(X\mid L)=\frac14\cdot1+\frac34\cdot\mathbb E(X\mid L)$$

Now realize that: $$\mathbb E(X\mid L)=-1+\mathbb EX$$

This because we are back in start position with one dollar less in our pocket.

So:$$\mathbb EX=\frac14+\frac34(-1+\mathbb EX)$$

From this equality we deduce easily that: $$\mathbb EX=-2$$

---

Another route:

Let $Y$ denote the number of games that in total will be played.

Then $Y$ has Geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac14$.

Further we observe that: $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y=n]=2-n$$
From this we are allowed to conclude that: $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=2-Y$$

Then applying the general rule:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]]$$we find:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb 2-Y=2-\frac1{\frac14}=2-4=-2$$

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of your geometric is

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{p}=4$$

Thus, the average loss is

$$-1\times 3+1=-2$$

This because the expected trials are 4: 3 losses before the first winning game

Comment: I did not understand how did we use the geometric expectation for this answer.